# How can I reduce the fontsize of the subsection and subsubsection titles in the Table of Contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize

I am using the following document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[maxlevel=3]{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, language=french]{biblatex}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{FreeSerif}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@dottedtocline}
{\rightskip\@tocrmarg}
{\rightskip\@tocrmarg plus 4em \hyphenpenalty\@M}
{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
```

How can I reduce the size of the subsection and subsubsection titles in the Table of Contents ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using `titlesec.sty`, you could use the companion package `titletoc.sty` and customize your TOC:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{section}[1.5pc]
  {\bfseries\filright}
  {\contentslabel{1.5pc}}{\hspace*{-1.5pc}}
  {\mdseries\titlerule*[0.7pc]{.}\bfseries\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}[3.5pc]
  {\addvspace{0.1pc}\filright\footnotesize}
  {\contentslabel{2pc}}{\hspace*{2pc}}
  {\titlerule*[0.7pc]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsubsection}[5.5pc]
  {\addvspace{0.1pc}\filright\tiny}
  {\contentslabel{2pc}}{\hspace*{-2pc}}
  {\titlerule*[0.7pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section} \lipsum
\subsection{Sub-Section} \lipsum
\subsubsection{Subsub-Section} \lipsum
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I also need to enlarge the space between the section and the subsection numbers and their title. For now, I have the following results: "11.2Lorem ipsum" or "11.2.2Lorem ipsum"

Comment: I fount it myself using the \usepackage{tocloft} with \setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{6pt}

Comment: @Leo - You can achieve that also by customizing the values of `\titlecontents{subsection}[4.5pc]` and `{\contentslabel{3pc}}`.  Check the documentation of `titlesec` for more information.  Further, I suggest you use either `tocloft.sty` or `titletoc.sty` and not both at same time.